# Refresh menu item in view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**Context**

I'm building a plugin for eclipse 3.4 and more.
I have a view with id `mrp.view` with a menuContribution set to `toolbar:mrp.view`.
This menuContribution has some command, and I have this one:

```
<handler
    class="mrp.handlers.export"
    commandId="mrp.commands.export">
</handler>

<command
    commandId="mrp.commands.export"
    label="My command"
    style="push">
</command>
```

My handler, `mrp.handlers.export` has a dynamic ìsEnabled()` method, looking like that :

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return !getMySelection().isEmpty();
}
```

**Question**

How can I refresh the button on my toolbar when data changed ?
(refresh is done automatically if I click anothr button of the toolbar, but if I don't...)

**I tried..**

```
ICommandService service = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
service.refreshElements("mrp.commands.export", null);
```

But it doesn't seems to do anything.

Also this one:

```
public class Export extends AbstractHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    setBaseEnabled(!getSelection().isEmpty());
}

    // ....
}
```

It is called, but the icon on my view's menu is not refreshed (on eclipse 3.7).
Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Ok that's weird, it works out of the box on Eclipse 4.2... 
But still not working on 3.4-3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanls to Paul Webster's answer, I got it working.

```
public class Export extends AbstractHandler implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public Export() {
        Activator.getDefault().AddListener(this);
        setBaseEnabled(!getMySelection().isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        // My handler
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(Activator.EVENT_SELECTION_CHANGED)) {
            boolean before = isEnabled();
            boolean after = !getMySelection().isEmpty();

            if (after != before) {
                setBaseEnabled(after);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: setBaseEnabled(*) does fire the handler changed event, I can see it in the code.

Comment: You're right, it does (for 3.6.1 and probably others version also - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.core/commands/3.6.0/org/eclipse/core/commands/AbstractHandler.java#AbstractHandler.setBaseEnabled%28boolean%29).
I will try again without firing when I get access to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your handler must fire an event when it's enablement changes.  If you have the change update your handler using *org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler.setBaseEnabled(boolean)* it will fire the required event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is still not working. (see my edit on the question)